# Prevent multiple rating

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig, rating

A user can be rated by another user, I would like to allow only one vote. I have decided to use cookie, once a user vote a cookie is set in the browser, when he will refresh the page the user will have a message telling him that he has already rated.

The problem is if the user try to rated another user he will have a message telling him that he has already voted, but he didn't yet.

I'm using this star rating plugin: [jQuery Raty](https://github.com/Jacob87/raty-fa)

This is what have done :

**StarRatingController.php**

```
/**
 * Return the result of rating action
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function rateAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $contentId = (int)$request->request->get('contentId');
    $score = (float)$request->request->get('score');
    $starrating = $this->get('fly_starrating_service');
    $average = $starrating->save( $contentId, $score );
    $response = new Response();
    $cookie = new Cookie('star_rating', 'rated', time()+3600 * 3 , '/', null, false, false);
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
    return $response->setContent($average);
}
```

**UserShow.html.twig**

```
{% if app.request.cookies.has('star_rating') %}
<p>You have already rated</p>
    {{ render(controller( "IdeatoStarRatingBundle:StarRating:alreadyRated", {contentId:entity.id} ) ) }}
{% else %}
    {{ render(controller( "IdeatoStarRatingBundle:StarRating:displayRate", {contentId:entity.id} ) ) }}
{% endif %}
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.alreadyRated').raty({
        path: '/symfony/web/bundles/ideatostarrating/images/',
        score: function() {
            return $(this).data('score');
        },

        readOnly: function() {


            return true;//$(this).attr('data-readonly') == 'true'
        },
        click: function(score, evt) {
            var t = $(this);
            var url = t.data('route');
            var data = {
                contentId: t.data('contentid'),
                score: score
            };
            t.raty('readOnly', true);

            $.post( url, data)
                .done(function(result){
                    t.raty('score', result);
                    t.trigger('isr-rated', { score: score, average: result });
                })
                .fail(function(){
                    alert('An error occurred. Please try again');
                    t.raty('readOnly', false);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you should simply save in a database which user has voted another user..?

Comment: Yes good idea, but how can I allow the same user to vote after 3 days the same user that he has already voted for ?

Comment: @Sirius, that's a different requirement from what you originally asked. But it's easy to do. Something like `if ($today >= $lastVoteDay + 3) { ... }`. You should be able to get the date of the most recent vote from your database, right?

Comment: @Sirius Did you even check my answer?

Comment: Not a good solution for cookies.   1. User rates 2. User clears cookies (which is *automatic* for some browsers/plugins when the browser closes)  3. User rates again.

Answer (score 3):

This should really be implemented in the server side, while you give a duplicate rating, it should not accept and return an error message. If reloading page fixes it, then in the client side, what you can do is, disable or disallow raty after it has been rated upon.

```
$('div').raty('readOnly', true);
```

Technically, your code should look like:

```
$('div').raty('click', function () {
  $(this).raty('readOnly', true);
});
```

**Added Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').raty({
    'click': function () {
      $(this).raty('readOnly', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<base href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.7.1/images/" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.7.1/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.7.1/jquery.raty.min.css" />
<div></div>
```